# The ruby def << syntax for defining methods

Tags: ruby, savon, function

Im trying to work my way through the Savon gem's source code and I found this line..

```
def initialize
  @documents = []
end

def <<(document)
  @documents << document
end
```

I was curious as to what the `def <<` method does. And why he might have elected to use that syntax over something (maybe) more conventional.

the source code can be found at:
https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/master/lib/savon/wsdl/document_collection.rb

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`def <<` literally creates a new method called `<<`.  Looking at the [Ruby Operator Expressions](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) reference, you can see a handful of those are methods that can be implemented, overridden, etc.

Nothing "unconventional" or special about it, just kind of weird if you're used to languages where that's handled in a special way.

Answer (score 3):

<< in Ruby is used to add an element, e.g. pushing into an array

```
[1,2,3] << 4
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

by defining << you can use this nice syntax in your class to push in arbitrary objects like this:

```
my_custom_class << object
```